# How can I read from and write to a binary file simultaneously?

Tags: file, matlab, file-io, binary, fwrite

I want to change the value of a couple of bytes in a large binary file using MATLAB's `fwrite` command. What I am trying to do is open the file using:

```
fopen(filename,'r+',precision);
```

Then read down the file using:

```
fread(fid,NUM,'int32');
```

This all works. Once I get to the file position where I want to write (overwrite) the values of the next bytes, I use the command:

```
fwrite(fid,variable_name,'int32');
```

Then I close the file:

```
fclose(fid);
```

So then I go back and re-read the file and these bytes haven't changed!

So is this not possible? Or is `'r+'` the wrong thing to use?

Comment: Please show your code so we can reproduce easier.

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation for [`fopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-permission):

> To read and write to the same file:
>
> - Open the file with a value for `permission` that includes a plus sign, `'+'`.
> - Call `fseek` or `frewind` between read and write operations. For example, do not call `fread` followed by `fwrite`, or `fwrite` followed by `fread`, unless you call `fseek` or `frewind` between them.

In short, you need to call [`fseek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) before you call [`fwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html):

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r+', precision);
data = fread(fid, NUM, 'int32');
fseek(fid, 0, 'cof');
fwrite(fid, variable_name, 'int32');
fclose(fid);
```

In fact, if you don't actually need to read anything from the file, and just need to move to a given position in the file, I would just use `fseek` in place of your call to [`fread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html). For example:

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r+', precision);
fseek(fid, NUM*4, 'bof');
fwrite(fid, variable_name, 'int32');
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read to know which byte to change keep a count of how many bytes you have to skip (4 bytes each int or float for instance).

```
bytesToSkip = 0;
not_the_value_you_want = true;
bytesPerValue = 4; %for a float or int

while not_the_value_you_want

...some code here...

  if 'this is it'

  not_the_value_you_want = false; % adapt this to your taste

  else

  bytesToSkip += bytesPerValue;

  end;

...maybe more code here...

end;
```

Try this after:

```
fileID = fopen('YourFile.bin','w+');
fseek(fileID,bytesToSkip,'bof'); %'bof' stands for beginning of file
fwrite(fileID,newValue);
fclose(fileID);
```